# Sending files through Socket from Javascript to Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket, django-channels

I am trying to add a feature in my chat app(with Django-channels) that allows users sending files.
I am searching for a way that sends files from Javascript to Django.

I am using this code in Javascript :

```
    // Access the file using fileInput.files[0]
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    // Read file data using FileReader API
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      var fileContent = event.target.result;
      // Send file data via WebSocket
      var data = {
        'command': 'file_included_message',
        'file': {
          'name': file.name,
          'content': fileContent,
        },

      };
      chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

and this code for the consumer(in Django):

```
        file_content = file_data['content']  # Base64 encoded file content
        # Save the file to a temporary location
        file_content_decoded = base64.b64decode(file_content)
    # Save the file to a temporary location
        file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(file_name))
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(file_content_decoded)
```